# Can't get a div to fill it's container scroll-able width

Tags: css

I have a wrapper width fixed width - 300px;
I have a child, content, width width 600px - causing the container to have scrolling.
I have another child, header, that I want to stretch the entire width of the wrapper. I say width 100% - but I only get 300px. I want it to get 600px (the full scrollable width of the wrapper)

I can probably solve this with Flex, but I want to know if there is another way.

Here's a screenshot of my problem:
[image]

How do I do that?

```css
.wrapper{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  overflow:auto;
  background-color:gray;
}
.header{
  background-color:red;
  width:100%;
  height:30px;
}
.content{
  height:100px;
  width:600px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
  
  </div>
  <div class="content">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: am i miss understanding or are you trying to set width of all to 300px. ??? your content width now is set to 600px and that is why it overflows ..

Comment: You should give wrapper, width:600px;

Comment: I think I  get what you are asking now, I had to read it few times.. Set the .header to width: 600px as well .. when you set it to 100% what happens is div inherits part width of 300px so if you want the red bar to go to the end you will have to over ride the parent by setting width in px not %

Comment: The width 600px that was set in the content was to simulate my problem. In reality I would have a verying content (columns of a grid) and getting their total width manually is a pain.
Still I want a header to span them all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems the solution is to add an inner wrapper, inside the wrapper, that contains the header and content, and set that `inner-wrapper` to `display:inline-block`

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: gray;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

.content {
  height: 100px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <div class="header">

    </div>
    <div class="content">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can `display` the `.wrapper` as `grid` with `grid-auto-rows: min-content` to "glue" their *items* together:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: min-content; /* or: "align-content: start" */
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: gray;
}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

.content {
  height: 100px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
  
  </div>
  <div class="content">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm concern that display:grid doesn't have enough browser support. see:
https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

Is there a way to do that without css grid?

Comment: Anyway I can do that with flexbox?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you set `.header { width: 100% }` and it is getting its parent width, which is 300px.

You can set a class with the desired width and set it to the elements you would like to have wider width then the parent.

```css
.wrapper{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  overflow:auto;
  background-color:gray;
}
.header{
  background-color:red;
  min-width: 100%;
  height:30px;
}
.content{
  height:100px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
.wide-content {
  width:600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header wide-content">
  
  </div>
  <div class="content wide-content">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that the content is varying in width and I want an horizontal scroll.
I want the header to span the width of the content, while I don't really know the actual content width

Comment: So put your `.header` element inside the `.content` element... Otherwise use JavaScript to calculate the width.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using a wrapper for the content and set scroll to that wrapper to prevent the `header` from scrolling.
Also note the height of the `content-wrapper`: *100% height - height of header*

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: gray;
}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
}

.content {
  height: 100px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It wouldn't solve my problem - since the header may also need a scroll - I may have columns outside my view that I want both the data and the header to scroll to.